# Removing tkinter frame without memory leak

Tags: python, tkinter, memory

After destroying a first child frame, and initializing a second frame, the parent object still retains some memory of the existence of the first, as indicated by the `2` in `.!frame2`.

My questions are,

- How is the object keeping track of its past children if the children have been destroyed?
- Is there a best practice or some other procedure to reverse/maintain this?

While the sample code below is simple, my actual application involves destroying and creating hundreds of children frames and I've noticed it slows down when many frames are packed.

Code

```
import tkinter

x = tk.Tk()
tk.Frame(x)
x.winfo_children()[0].destroy()
tk.Frame(x)
print(x.winfo_children())
```

Output

```
[<tkinter.Frame object .!frame2>]
```

Comment: *and I've noticed it slows down when many frames are packed.* If you pack hundreds of frames into your window then I guess you misunderstanding something, cause as long as you haven't a monitor as big as wall, there seems to be no need for this.

Answer (score 1):

> How is the object keeping track of its past children if the children have been destroyed?

It's just a simple dictionary that maintains a counter for each widget type, for each master widget. Here's the snippet of code that updates the counter (from `tkinter/__init__.py`):

```
class BaseWidget(Misc):
    ...    
    def _setup(self, master, cnf):
        ...
        if not name:
            name = self.__class__.__name__.lower()
            if master._last_child_ids is None:
                master._last_child_ids = {}
            count = master._last_child_ids.get(name, 0) + 1
            master._last_child_ids[name] = count
            if count == 1:
                name = '!%s' % (name,)
            else:
                name = '!%s%d' % (name, count)
```

> Is there a best practice or some other procedure to reverse/maintain this?

The best practice is to not worry about it. The counter takes up only a few bytes per widget.

You can avoid the creation of the counter if you set the `name` attribute for every widget that you create. Depending on how your widgets are organized, that may only save you a couple of kilobytes of memory.

A deeply nested hierarchy could conceivably reach into the tens or hundreds of kilobytes, but it would be pretty difficult to ever reach a single megabyte without tkinter failing for other reasons.